# jQuery not working on first click, but working with every other click

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make restaurant menu. I wrote a function, but it's not working on first click, but with every next click is ok.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu-options").on('click', '#show-meat', function() {
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (clicks) {
      $(".menu-options-choice-veget").hide("slow");
      $(".menu-options-choice-vegan").hide("slow");
      $(".menu-options-choice-meat").animate({
        'margin-right': '-800px'
      }, 'slow');
    } else {
      $(".menu-options-choice-veget").show("slow");
      $(".menu-options-choice-vegan").show("slow");
      $(".menu-options-choice-meat").animate({
        'margin-right': '0px'
      });
    }
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu" id="menu-options">
  <ul>
    <li><button type="button" class="menu-otpions-button" id="show-meat">Meat</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="menu-otpions-button" id="show-veg">Vegetarian</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="menu-otpions-button" id="show-vegan">Vegan</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `#show-meat` element has no `data-clicks` attribute.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan jQuery's `data` function doesn't need the `data-xxx` attribute, it has its own implementation of it.

Comment: Exactly. So the value is `false` by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because there is no `data-clicks` attribute on the buttons when the page loads. As such when you first click a button `clicks` will be `false`, so it tries to hide the content. You need to invert this flag for the logic to work as you intend, so the element is shown on the first click:

```
var clicks = !$(this).data('clicks');
```

Here's a full working snippet:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu-options").on('click', '#show-meat', function() {
    var clicks = !$(this).data('clicks');    
    if (clicks) {
      $(".menu-options-choice-veget, .menu-options-choice-vegan").hide("slow");
      $(".menu-options-choice-meat").animate({
        'margin-right': '-800px'
      }, 'slow');
    } else {
      $(".menu-options-choice-veget, .menu-options-choice-vegan").show("slow");
      $(".menu-options-choice-meat").animate({
        'margin-right': '0px'
      });
    }
    $(this).data("clicks", clicks);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu" id="menu-options">
  <ul>
    <li><button type="button" class="menu-otpions-button" id="show-meat">Meat</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="menu-otpions-button" id="show-veg">Vegetarian</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="menu-otpions-button" id="show-vegan">Vegan</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu-options-choice-veget">Vegetarian</div>
<div class="menu-options-choice-vegan">Vegan</div>
<div class="menu-options-choice-meat">Meat</div>
```